# Should one override hashcode to store objects in ArrayList?

Tags: java

Should we override hashCode() method to store a user-defined object in an ArrayList. If there is a class called Employee in which two fields id and name are there.

Comment: why not using HashSet or HashMap with id as key?

Comment: ALWAYS override hashCode() when you override equals(). This is a no-brainer. And Effective Java says you should, so Just Do It(tm).

Comment: @fge It's not clear the OP needs to override `equals`, though.

Comment: I guess there is no real need overriding hashCode for List but we should do it for good practices?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`hashCode` is not used by `ArrayList`, but `equals` is used to determine if an object is located in the List, and whenever you override `equals`, you should override `hashCode` too, since equal objects should have the same `hashCode`.